# How to extract a value which match all the group by rows

Tags: pandas

- DF is below
- extract a value from `Col1` which matches
- b is the only value which matches x,y,z

```
    d = {"Col1":['a','d','b','c','a','d','b','b'],
    "Col2":['x','y','x','z','x','y','z','y']}
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Output

b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want compare values by cutom list first aggregate `set`s, compare by another one and filter index values:

```
s = df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].agg(set) 

a = s.index[s == set(['x','y','z'])].tolist()
print (a)
['b']
```

If need compare by all possible unique values of column `Col2`:

```
s = df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].agg(set) 

a = s.index[s == set(df['Col2'])].tolist()
print (a)
['b']
```